# tweepy API.user_timeline returns empty list

Tags: python, tweepy

I am building a Telegram bot that will forward Elon Musk's latest Twitter.
Even if it works without any problems, occasionly index error is occured.
"api_user_timeline" returns empty list.

To find out the problem, print() was added and driven, but an error occurred in the second iteration of while().

```
import telepot
import os
import tweepy
import time
import requests

token = '' #telepot bot token
user_list=[''] #user id
bot = telepot.Bot(token)

consumer_key = "" # Twitter API Key
consumer_secret = "" # Twitter API Secret Key
access_token = "" # Twitter Access Key
access_token_secret = "" # Twitter Access Secret Key

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
 
user_id='44196397'

status =  api.user_timeline(user_id=user_id,exclude_replies=True,include_rts=False, tweet_mode = 'extended')
print("[status] "+status_present[0].full_text)

while True:
    time.sleep(30)
    status_present =  api.user_timeline(user_id=user_id,exclude_replies=True, include_rts=False, tweet_mode = 'extended')
    print("[status_present] "+status_present[0].full_text)
    if status[0].full_text!=status_present[0].full_text:
        for i in user_list:
            bot.sendMessage(i,status_present[0].full_text)
    status=status_present
```

here's output print() message & error message below
I ran it in jupyter notebook.

```
[status] Given that Twitter serves as the de facto public town square, failing to adhere to free speech principles fundamentally undermines democracy. 

[status_present] Given that Twitter serves as the de facto public town square, failing to adhere to free speech principles fundamentally undermines democracy. 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9460/139022525.py in <module>
     56     time.sleep(30)
     57     status_present =  api.user_timeline(user_id=user_id,exclude_replies=True, include_rts=False, tweet_mode = 'extended')
---> 58     print("[status_present] "+status_present[0].full_text)
     59     if status[0].full_text!=status_present[0].full_text:
     60         for i in user_list:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to know why this phenomenon occurs. I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is anything to fix in the code. Thanks